# How to implement a common base view for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

All of my application's pages share the same layout and a set of UI elements, which I've been trying to make a reusable component out of.

I've gone the subclassing road, making an "abstract" subclass of UIViewController to hold the base logic for navigation, and a nib file laying out the UI.

I've spent some time unit-testing the base class, which works as expected, but ran into inheritance related issues when I started actually subclassing it.

I won't go into details, since I'm thinking this was actually a bad idea, and composition is the way to go, but I thought I'd ask before wasting any more time...

What would be the best approach here ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a base class, as you've done. Without any details, it's hard to help you further.

If they all use the same layout, couldn't you just make it one class?

Comment: Thanks this made me look into it a bit further, and I figured out how to reuse a base nib file, by calling the following method in the base class' viewDidLoad : [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BaseNibName" owner:self options:nil];

Comment: hmm are you sure about this bit, I have some unit tests that fail oddly, so I tried it, but now I get : loaded the "MyBaseViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set. Tried adding the views from the array one by one too, same issue...